# Where to store JSON files in spring, gradle

Tags: java, json, database, spring-boot, file

I'm trying to find a right place to save JSON file. JSON files would look like :

```
{
  "itemId" : "ITEM_ID",
  "name" : "ITEM_NAME",
  "itemType" : "ITEM_TYPE",
  "effects": [
    {
      "type": "statModifier",
      "name": "intelligence",
      "value": 10.0
    }
  ]
}
```

My current directory structure looks like this.

```
src/
    java/
    resources/
        json/
            json_file.json  
        application.properites
    webapp/
        css/
        html/
```

The requirments are

1. JSON file should be able to being updated during run-time.
2. Client's should not be able to access the file.

The current project structure is like

src/main/java

src/main/resources

src/main/webapp

and there is no other directory under main

Below is the options I have considered.

1. **resources**

   I've heard that 'resources' directory is for read-only files and not appropriate for files that might be updated.
2. **webapp**

   I've heard that 'webapp' is for the files about web(html, css, js, ...). So putting my JSON files would not be good.
3. **DBMS**

   I've have thought about it but I prefer to store informations in JSON. I could use DBMS if there is no other options but still I believe there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're right about the limitations of your options:

> resources:

This directory is indeed meant for static resources like configuration files that shouldn't be modified during runtime.

> webapp:

This directory is for web application resources like HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. Placing JSON files here would be unconventional and potentially expose them to clients.

> DBMS:

While you could store the data in a database, using a separate JSON format offers advantages like flexibility and ease of use.
Here are some better options for saving your JSON files based on your requirements:

1. Dedicated data directory:

Create a new directory named **"resources"** under the

> src/main/resources" directory

.
Save your JSON files in this directory.
Use libraries like java.nio.file or frameworks like Spring to access and update these files at runtime. This approach is standard practice and keeps your data separate from other application components.

2. Classpath with encryption:

Place your JSON files in the "src/main/resources" directory.
Use a library like "Jasypt" to encrypt the JSON content before saving the files.
Access the encrypted files at runtime using the library and decrypt them before reading the data. This approach offers better security by obscuring the content, but requires additional code for encryption and decryption.

3. Configuration management tool:

Consider using a configuration management tool like Spring Cloud Config or Apache ZooKeeper.
These tools store configuration files (including JSON) externally and allow for centralized management and dynamic updates during runtime. This approach requires additional setup but offers features like version control and distributed access.
Choosing the best option depends on factors like your project's complexity, security requirements, and desired level of control. The dedicated data directory is the simplest and most common approach, while the other options may be better suited for specific situations like centralized configuration or enhanced security.
and this code for example

```
import java.nio.file.*;
public class JsonFileManager {
private static final String JSON_DIRECTORY =             "src/main/resources/json_files";
private static final String EXTERNAL_DIRECTORY = "external_directory";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Path jsonDirectory = Paths.get(JSON_DIRECTORY);
    Path externalDirectory = Paths.get(EXTERNAL_DIRECTORY);
}}
```

Comment: So if I go with 'dedicated data directory', My json directory would be like 'src/main/resources/resources/json_file.json'? Also, could you explain more about the difference between 'dedicated data directory' and just storing json files in resources? To me, it seems like both are the same in that they use resources differently from their original purpose.

Comment: show please your cod and your folder sort .

Comment: Al Munajjed I added my directory structure in my question.